# Как между итерациями в цикле js сделать интервал

Tags: javascript

Почему не работает данная функция?
Можно ли обойтись без цикла, для вывода по интервалам?

```
var i
function go() {
  var poem = 'Ночь, улица, фонарь, !!! аптека,* Бессмысленный и тусклый свет.* Живи еще !!! хоть четверть века -* Все будет так. Исхода !!! нет.* Умрешь - начнешь опять сначала* И повторится !!! все, как встарь:* Ночь, ледяная !!! рябь канала,* Аптека, улица, !!! фонарь.*';
  poem = poem.replace(/!!!/g, ' ');
  var arr = poem.split('*');
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    setInterval(function(){alert(arr[i])}, 3000);
  }
}

go()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция не работает, потому что к моменту выполнения даже самого первого колбэка `setInterval`-a переменная `i` равна `arr.length`. Не говоря уже о том, что запускается множество таймеров.

```js
function go() {
  var poem = 'Ночь, улица, фонарь, !!! аптека,* Бессмысленный и тусклый свет.* Живи еще !!! хоть четверть века -* Все будет так. Исхода !!! нет.* Умрешь - начнешь опять сначала* И повторится !!! все, как встарь:* Ночь, ледяная !!! рябь канала,* Аптека, улица, !!! фонарь.*';
  poem = poem.replace(/!!!/g, ' ');
  var arr = poem.split('*');
  var i = 0;
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (i >= arr.length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log("The end.");
    } else {
      console.log(i + ": " + arr[i++]);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

go();
```

с циклом:

```js
function go() {
  var poem = 'Ночь, улица, фонарь, !!! аптека,* Бессмысленный и тусклый свет.* Живи еще !!! хоть четверть века -* Все будет так. Исхода !!! нет.* Умрешь - начнешь опять сначала* И повторится !!! все, как встарь:* Ночь, ледяная !!! рябь канала,* Аптека, улица, !!! фонарь.*';
  poem = poem.replace(/!!!/g, ' ');
  var arr = poem.split('*');
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    setTimeout((function(index){ 
      return function() {
        console.log(index + ": " + arr[index])
      };
    })(i), 1000 * (i + 1))
  }
}

go();
```

Comment: То есть цикл не нужен там вообще?

Comment: @AsanOzis да, цикл не нужен - `setInterval` его заменяет